# Spatie gave an error like "User have not permission for this page access."

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-permission

I am using laravel's spatie/permission package on Laravel 5.8 in admin panel.I have setup all links and table perfect but somehow I got an error like "User have not permission for this page access."

I took reference from this URL:- https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-58-user-roles-and-permissions-tutorialexample.html

My routes

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware' => ['admin.auth']], function () {

    Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
    Route::resource('cmspage', 'CmsPageController');
    Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
    Route::resource('roles', 'RoleController');
    Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');

});
```

my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;
use DB;


class RoleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('permission:role-list|role-create|role-edit|role-delete', ['only' => ['index','store']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:role-create', ['only' => ['create','store']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:role-edit', ['only' => ['edit','update']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:role-delete', ['only' => ['destroy']]);  
    }


    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $roles = Role::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(5);
        return view('admin.roles.index',compact('roles'))
            ->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }


    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $permission = Permission::get();
        return view('roles.create',compact('permission'));
    }


    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|unique:roles,name',
            'permission' => 'required',
        ]);


        $role = Role::create(['name' => $request->input('name')]);
        $role->syncPermissions($request->input('permission'));


        return redirect()->route('roles.index')
                        ->with('success','Role created successfully');
    }
    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $role = Role::find($id);
        $rolePermissions = Permission::join("role_has_permissions","role_has_permissions.permission_id","=","permissions.id")
            ->where("role_has_permissions.role_id",$id)
            ->get();


        return view('admin.roles.show',compact('role','rolePermissions'));
    }


    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $role = Role::find($id);
        $permission = Permission::get();
        $rolePermissions = DB::table("role_has_permissions")->where("role_has_permissions.role_id",$id)
            ->pluck('role_has_permissions.permission_id','role_has_permissions.permission_id')
            ->all();


        return view('roles.edit',compact('role','permission','rolePermissions'));
    }


    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'permission' => 'required',
        ]);


        $role = Role::find($id);
        $role->name = $request->input('name');
        $role->save();


        $role->syncPermissions($request->input('permission'));


        return redirect()->route('roles.index')
                        ->with('success','Role updated successfully');
    }
    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        DB::table("roles")->where('id',$id)->delete();
        return redirect()->route('roles.index')
                        ->with('success','Role deleted successfully');
    }
}
```

My auth.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'customer',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admin',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'api',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
        'customer' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'customer',
        ]
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

  'providers' => [
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'customer' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Customer::class,
        ]
        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

  'passwords' => [
        'admin' => [
            'provider' => 'admin',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],

    ],

];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, and solve the problem the same way. Enter roles and permissions manually in the database (phpmyadmin in my db local).
Example: I add a role-list to the table (`roles`, `role_has_permissions`, `model_has_roles`, `model_has_permissions`).

Okay, now you open the role view and try adding another role in the application

[image: MyScreenShoot]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to create the permissions you want.
If you work with guard then you should mention the guard_name in the permission create array.

```
Permission::create(['name' => 'admin', 'guard_name' => 'admin']);
$role = Role::create([
        'name' => 'admin',
        'guard_name' => 'admin',
    ]);

    $role->givePermissionTo('admin');
```

Here is the seed example [PermissionSeeder](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v4/advanced-usage/seeding)

Here is the complete example of [Spatie Permissions Laravel](https://ateequrrahman150.medium.com/spatie-permissions-with-laravel-f3eda6694d4)